# Slide to new set of coordinates on Google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm writing a script that loads a location on Google maps based on Longitude and Latitude coordinates. I also have a drop-down that allows user to select new location. Is there a way to slide the map to a new set of coordinates using some sort of animation instead jumping from one map view to another?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `panTo`-method of the [map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#Map).

> *If the change is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated.*

Answer (score 0):

As you are Using JQuery, you can use a lot of Libraries, plugins available online in order to provide a slider in your map transitions. I like this one and have tried before you can give it a shot...

http://www.ajaxshake.com/en/JS/239331/create-a-slider-for-google-maps-with-jquery-googlemaps.html

Hope that works in your case.

Comment: I like it but I think it also uses panTo method because the points are within the same screen. Unfortunately in my case they are not.